# How to change the font of MFC SysLink Control

Tags: fonts, hyperlink, mfc

I'm trying to show some description with link. The link is mixed with static words, like following style:

Please search by [google](https://www.goolge.com) or other search engine, visit [my blog](https://www.baidu.com).

I can achieve this by using MFC syslink control, question is how to change the font(style,size) of syslink control? Is there any other control can achieve similar function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a font using `CFont` class, with custom size and style. Use this font in `CWnd::SetFont` just like other dialog controls:

```
//declare class members:
class CMyDialog : public CDialog
{
    CFont m_font; //declare font here, not a temporary font on the stack
    CLinkCtrl m_linkCtrl;
    ...
};

BOOL CMyDialog::OnInitDialog()
{
    BOOL res = CDialog::OnInitDialog();

    //get current dialog font
    CFont *dialogfont = GetFont();
    LOGFONT logfont;
    dialogfont->GetLogFont(&logfont);

    //create new font
    m_font.CreateFont(logfont.lfHeight, //change font height
        0, 0, 0, 
        FW_BOLD, TRUE, 0, 0, //change bold, italic, underline, strikeout
        0, 0, 0, logfont.lfQuality, 0, logfont.lfFaceName);

    m_linkCtrl.SubclassDlgItem(IDC_SYSLINK1, this);
    m_linkCtrl.SetFont(&m_font, TRUE);

    return res;
}
```

To change the color for syslink control, you have to tell the control to accept changes:

```
LITEM item = { 0 };
item.mask = LIF_ITEMINDEX | LIF_STATE;
item.state = LIS_DEFAULTCOLORS;
item.stateMask = LIS_DEFAULTCOLORS;
m_linkCtrl.SetItem(&item);
```

Then override `OnCtrlColor` to change text color

Comment: Thanks Barmak, I follow your description to create a new font like following:
CFont testFont;
testFont.CreateFont(20,0,0,0,
  FW_NORMAL,FALSE,FALSE,0,0,0,0,DEFAULT_QUALITY,0,_T

Comment: Thanks Barmak, I follow your description to create a new font like following:

`CFont testFont;`
`testFont.CreateFont(20,0,0,0,`
`FW_NORMAL,FALSE,FALSE,0,`
`0,0,0,DEFAULT_QUALITY,0,_T("Segoe UI"));`
`m_linkCtrl.SubclassDlgItem(IDC_SYSLINK1, this);`
`m_linkCtrl.SetFont(&testFont, TRUE);`
`


It come out that all syslink text show underline, not only the link text but the static text show underline too. Have you met this case?

Comment: That's a bug because you have created the font on the stack. Declare the font as a member data. See edit.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani wouldn't it be cleaner to create the new font based on the font returned by `GetFont()` instead of the one in the `NONCLIENTMETRICS` structure?

Comment: @MichaelWalz You are right. I changed it to use `GetFont()`